# UEFI ARM64 Synchronous Exception

Tags: exception, synchronous, arm64, uefi

I am developing an UEFI application for ARM64 (ARMv8-A) and I have come across the issue: "Synchronous Exceptions at 0xFF1BB0B8."
This value (0x0FF1BB0B8) is exception link register (ELR). ELR holds the exception return address.

There are a number of sources of Synchronous exceptions (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/AArch64-Exception-Handling/Synchronous-and-asynchronous-exceptions):

1. Instruction aborts from the MMU. For example, by reading an
   instruction from a memory location marked as Execute Never.
2. Data Aborts from the MMU. For example, Permission failure or alignment checking.
3. SP and PC alignment checking.
4. Synchronous external aborts. For example, an abort when reading translation table.
5. Unallocated instructions.
6. Debug exceptions.

I can't update BIOS firmware to output more debug information. Is there any way to detect more precisely what causes Synchronous Exception?

Can I use the value of ELR (0x0FF1BB0B8) to locate the issue? I compile with -fno-pic -fno-pie options.

Comment: 0x0FF1BB0B8 should be the address in your code that causes the exception, right?  So you can disassemble your code around that address and see what the offending instruction is doing.  You may need a register or memory dump to figure out what's going on, or at least insert some prints before the crashing code.

Comment: Thanks for advice. 0x0FF1BB0B8 is not the address that causes exception, it's the address we are going to jump to when the exception occurs.

It turns out that UEFI has EFI_DEBUG_SUPPORT_PROTOCOL.RegisterExceptionCallback() function (UEFI Specification, Version 2.9, p. 868) which can be called when a given processor exception occurs. But it doesn't have an implemantation for arm64.

Comment: As far as code disassembly is concerned, it is quite a large project and it takes a lot of time to look for the cause of the exception. For example, if the reason it's a pointer which points to an incorrect address one has to look at a huge amount of code to understand why the pointer points to an incorrect address and which address is correct.

Comment: Moreover, when I insert some prints before the crashing code the exception disappears or it might move to another location.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but I recently debugged a Synchronous Exception on ARMv8.   I am fairly inexperienced in ARM debug, so please feel free help improve my answer. I hope that this helps someone else that is searching on this type of issue.

You should get a LOT of output about the exception in your UEFI application. The output from the exception handler does a little work for you and also gives you the raw exception reporting registers. I've highlighted some key things to look for:

```
Synchronous Exception at 0x00000000EFD52680  
PC 0x0000EFD52680 (0x0000EFD51000+0x00001680) [ 0] yourapp.dll
...
X0 0x00000000EFD57C66   X1 0x0000000000000003   X2 0x0000000000000000   X3 0x00000000FB952CA0  
...
SP 0x00000000FBA3A160  ELR 0x00000000EFD52680  SPSR 0x60000209  FPSR 0x00000000  
ESR 0x96000006          FAR 0x0000000000000002  
ESR : EC 0x25  IL 0x1  ISS 0x00000006  

Data abort: Translation fault, second level
```

1. Identify the failure. ARM failure information is at the bottom of the dump. My failure was *"Data abort: Translation fault, second level"*. Which is decoded from the The Exception Syndrome Register (ESR) as the link you noted in your question shows. (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/AArch64-Exception-Handling/Synchronous-and-asynchronous-exceptions)
   That page also tells you *"An exception is described as synchronous if it is generated as a result of execution or attempted execution of the instruction stream, and where the return address provides details of the instruction that caused it."*
2. Where the exception occurs. The program counter (PC) indicates the application load location and offset into the code.

```
PC 0x0000EFD52680 (0x0000EFD51000+0x00001680) [ 0] yourapp.dll
```

You'll need this for examining the UEFI application disassembly.
Note, this is the ELR.

3. Fault Address Register (FAR) is the address that caused the fault. IE, the location that was being accessed.

```
FAR 0x0000000000000002
```

So, this is already suspicious. The address is not in the program area.

4. Note the registers Xn and the Stack Pointer (SP).
5. Build the application with debug symbols and disassemble. I am using gcc -g and I can use objdump to get the disassembly.

```
$ objdump -D youapp.efi > yourapp.d
```

In my example, There is a problem in the code at 0x00001680 (PC) accessing 0x02 (FAR).
Here is the mixed disassembly:

```
  while (*s1) {
    167c:   78626806    ldrh    w6, [x0, x2]
      if (*s1 != *s2) {
    1680:   78626905    ldrh    w5, [x8, x2]    <-- Exception!
  while (*s1) {
    1684:   35000186    cbnz    w6, 16b4 <somefunction+0x9c>
```

The code at 0x1680 is loading a value from the location [x8, x2] into w5. And we can see that x8, x2 matches the FAR.

```
X2 0x0000000000000000
X8 0x0000000000000002
```

This code is optimized -0s, so there is some function in-lining and other optimization going on. I see that the code is in  and reading the disassembly, that there is a code path where x8 is not initialized.

Now I know that I'm looking for an uninitialized pointer in , and sure enough, there was a call to another function to initialize the pointer and it didn't! Fixed that!